# How to increase RAM size and database storage capacity in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have AWS linux based server with one project, and now I want to deploy another project on the same server. For this I want to know whether my existing memory is enough or should I have to increase the memory limit, and please let me know how to increase the memory limit.

Please refer the below images for available memory space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: well you got about 3GB ram to spare, if your new project needs <3GB ram then i guess it's ok. if it needs >=3GB ram then time for an upgrade - ps this question is probably more suited for serverfault.com than stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hanshenrik and what about the database storage. I mean for new project having 3GB of data.

Comment: if you have 3 GB of data you want to store in a database then you probably need to upgrade your disk space. you have 6GB disk space left, but many databases (at least MySQL and MariaDB and PostgreSQL) will use significantly more than 3GB disk space to store 3GB worth of data

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to using a database in AWS.

You can **install the database on the Amazon EC2 instance**. You will then be responsible for configuring and maintaining the database and doing backups. The up-side is that it can run on the same EC2 instance as your application.

Or, you can **use Amazon RDS to provide a database**. Amazon RDS can install, configure and operate the database for you, including taking backups. It runs on a separate computer so there are additional costs involved, but there are many benefits to keeping a database separate from the application, such as allowing you to scale your application separately to the database. Large applications often run across multiple computers and they can all connect to the one database on Amazon RDS.

From your description, it looks like you are going with the first option. You can increase the disk capacity of the Amazon EC2 instance by **increasing the size of the Amazon EBS disk volume** (and then do a reboot). If you desire more RAM, then Stop the instance, **change the [Instance Type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)** to something larger, then Start the instance again.

Comment: if you're using a filesystem that support live expansion (like ext4 or btrfs), is the reboot still required? shouldn't it be sufficient to just run `sudo growpart /dev/vda` + `sudo btrfs filesystem resize +100g /`  ?

Comment: I guess so. I know that Amazon Linux does a `resize2fs` for the root volume during the boot process, so it's an easy way to do it.